# SwiftUI grid - align center leading

Tags: swiftui, alignment, lazyvgrid

I have the following column structure defined for a `VGrid`:

```
let columns = [
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .topLeading),
    GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .topTrailing),
    GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .topTrailing),
]
```

However, for the first column, I want to align center vertically, but to the leading edge. There don't appear to be any options to do this (e.g. `.centerLeading`). Wondering if there is another way around this.

Comment: The new [Grid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid?changes=_6) might help the RC version of Xcode 14 would be out very soon